# Dynamically centering within a container div when the div is off the side of the screen? (Horizontal navigation layout)

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I have a horizontally laid out website (just a series of 6 sketches contained in divs, no concerns over usability with the odd navigation style).

To do this, I've declared a series of div sections which are relatively positioned, one after the other, left to right. In them, I have a wrapper div which I plan to use for easy placement, and finally a content div which holds my image/text.

However, I've coded myself into a corner which I don't know how to get out of.

I'd like to center the wrapper (and thus, content) div horizontally and vertically in each of the respective sections.

Yet I cannot do this, because I don't know how wide the user's screen is when they expand or contract it.

Example:
My overall body is 1200px wide. Each section is 2000px wide. Each wrapper and content is contained within.

- I can't declare "margin: 0 auto;" on my wrapper item, since it's going to position the wrapper in the middle of the WHOLE 2000px wide section...
- In fact, it would position it at around about 500 pixels in if my maths isn't off

I've coded a little snippet to show you the problem:

```
html { height: 100%; }

body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 12000px;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.section {
    height:  100%;
    background: url("../images/large-swirls.jpg") repeat scroll top right #fff; 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 2000px; /* I've declared it big enough to see my swirl image */
    z-index: 0 !important;
}

.wrapper {
    /* This is where I should center it horizontally and vertically */
    /* I can't use margin: 0 auto; because the wrapper is in a 2000px container */
}

.content {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto; /* The content is cleanly centered in my little box */
    width: 1000px;
}


<div class="section" id="sketch1">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Hello. I'm one of the sketch sections.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, can anyone advise me on how to lay it out so that I can center up a content div for sections which, essentially, run off the right hand side of the page? I just don't know how to declare such a thing for the wrapper class.

I suspect the answer might lie in some sort of position:absolute option? (But i'm not sure, never used those much).

I've also tried looking around at other horizontally navigable websites for ideas, but they all seem to align content to the left and then put padding on the side e.g. padding-left:500px.. which doesn't look good if you're on a big screen. It certainly isn't centered which is what I aim for now.

Any help with some ideas? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem.  You would not believe how many time I've tried to *just center the stupid idv* on a page (horizontal and vertical).  The best solution I have come up with to date is this use of tables.  If I want a box that will always be in the very middle of the screen all the time regardless of window resize, I will make a single cell table and use it's v and h align attributes (set to middle).  With your site, you could wrap each of these section in a table and float the tables.  Not the cleanest solution, but unfortunatly, there is little help out there (outside of some messy javascript) for those of us that just want to center something.

quick example of a table shadow box... thing:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color:#ddd" border="0">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td align="middle">
      <div>The Centered Element</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed use of tables, Joseph, that's something I hadn't considered. It does feel somewhat dirty though. I'll mark yours as the answer unless someone pipes up with an elegant alternative (I've not come across the JavaScript examples you mention - is there any tutorial you can point me towards?)

Comment: I can relate about the centering issue though.  I have tried that many times.  I don't know about any tutorials specifically, but one good resource is javascriptkit.com.  http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/static2.shtml for helps clarify how to get the window dimensions.  Good luck on your project! :)